# Joomla 2.5 display a contact in a module

Tags: joomla2.5

Is it possible to putt a Joomla 2.5 contact in a module?

I know how to assign a contact (group) to a menu, but could not find a way to get it into a module.

Answer (score 2):

You can write a custom module for this; not a custom html one but one in PHP. An example on how to display information in a module:

```
<?php
defined('_JEXEC') or die;

$db = JFactory::getDBO();
$db->setQuery('SELECT name, country FROM #__contact_details WHERE id = 1');
$contact = $db->loadObject();

$html = '<p>Name: ' . $contact->name . '</p>' .
        '<p>Country: ' . $contact->country . '</p>';

echo $html;
?>
```

The example above selects the name and country from the user with an ID = 1. You could allow a user to enter a parameter in the plugin settings to specify an ID manually, but that would require a little extra work.

If you need more details or help feel free to ask :)

Comment: Using this answer, makes it possible to also display contact information outside of the contact scope ie. on the offline.php page. Very useful!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom html module -- use firebug to pull the html for the contact, than paste it into a custom html module and voila you can put it wherever you want